# Elm files are not compiled by Webpack in Phoenix framework

Tags: webpack, phoenix-framework, elm

I have just converted my elm files from manual compilation to automated through Webpack, as it comes bundled in Phoenix framework.

Problem is that recompiling doesn't work well. If I delete all cached files and compiled output, it sometimes recompiles, but most often not. It looks like the output files are directly copied from somewhere (I don't know where) without any compilation taking place.

This is my webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
const HardSourceWebpackPlugin = require('hard-source-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env, options) => {
  const devMode = options.mode !== 'production';

  const srcPaths = [
    path.resolve(__dirname, './elm-db'),
    path.resolve(__dirname, './elm-ledger'),
  ];

  const elmRules = srcPaths.map(featurePath => ({
    test: new RegExp(`^${featurePath}.*elm$`),
    include: featurePath,
    exclude: [/elm-stuff/, /node_modules/],
    use: [
      {
        loader: require.resolve('elm-webpack-loader'),
        options: {
          cwd: featurePath,
          debug: options.mode === "development",
          optimize: options.mode === "production",
        },
      },
    ],
  }));

  return {
    optimization: {
      minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({ cache: true, parallel: true, sourceMap: devMode }),
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({}),
      ]
    },
    entry: {
      // 'app': './js/app.js',
      'main': './sass/main.sass',
      'db': './sass/db.sass',
      'ledger': './sass/ledger.sass',
      'client-db': './js/client_db.js',
      'client-ledger': './js/client_ledger.js',
    },
    output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../priv/static/js'),
      publicPath: '/js/',
    },
    devtool: devMode ? 'inline-source-map' : undefined,
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
          use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            { loader: 'css-loader', options: {} },
            { loader: 'sass-loader', options: {} },
          ],
        },
      ].concat(elmRules)
    },
    plugins: [
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '../css/[name].css' }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'static/', to: '../' }]),
    ].concat(devMode ? [new HardSourceWebpackPlugin()] : []),
  }
};
```

This is my client_db.js file:

```
import clientDb from "./routes_db"

import socket from "./socket"

let db_channel = socket.channel("ledgers", {})

db_channel.join()
    .receive("ok", resp => {
        console.log("Joined successfully", resp)
        clientDb(db_channel)
    })
    .receive("error", resp => { console.log("Unable to join", resp) })
    .receive("timeout", () => console.log("Networking issue. Still waiting..."))
```

This is the start of routes_db.js:

```
import { Elm } from "../elm-db/src/Main.elm"

let clientDb = (channel) => {
    console.log("CONNECTED")

    const app = Elm.Main.init()

    app.ports.loadLedgers.subscribe(() => {
        channel.push("load_ledgers", {})
    })
...
```